# [Android]:kmlparser exception while accessing soap web service in android

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am using below code to access soap web service. But I am getting exception .Please help.

Exception :

```
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: 
START_TAG {http://schedmas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}
Envelop (position:START_TAG<definitions targetNamespace='urn:schedule'>@2:425 in java.io.InputStreamreader@43d36520)
```

Code:

```
public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
         request.addProperty("access_key", "5rrtrtr");
         request.addProperty("type", "facebook");
         request.addProperty("access_secrete", "5rtrt");
         request.addProperty("message", "5");
         request.addProperty("date", "2010/12/16");
         request.addProperty("time", "05:10:00");
         request.addProperty("ampm", "AM");
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request
         HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
         httpTransport.debug = true;  
         httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request
         SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
         return result;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but in my case I checked out the url & namespace.I am got the same error.Please try out that first.